# How to create a view of counts of taxonomy reference fields by each user?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type that contains a taxonomy term reference field. each user can create unlimited nodes of this content type and select different term at each time. now we want make a view of count of this terms selected by users as a table like this:

[image]

is there any plugin to support create these type of tables in views? or we should do it programmatically? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the Advanced > Other section of the view, you should be able to enable aggregation.

Comment: thanks for your answer but aggregation doesn't work in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no solution to create such kind of view using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. But the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) can be used for this type of reporting. More specifically by using its facility to create a [Display of a table in ***crosstab*** format](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.renderers#frxcrosstab).

A ***crosstab*** table is a table with a special layout. It is formatted as a grid, with:

- the **rows** representing one or more (combinations of) facts, such as countries or regions, names of persons (or users) like employees / salespeople (or user IDs / user names), etc.
- the **columns** representing one or more other facts, such as periods (months of a year, years, etc), available types/flavors of something (like types of errors), etc.
- the **intersections of rows and columns** containing the actual information (data), such as summarized information (counts of something), timestamps, etc. and which might (optionally) **include a hyperlink to a drill-down report**.

Below is a sample of such ***crosstab*** report (including drilldown links also, i.e. the numbers in red in it):

[image]

Refer to [my comment in the Forena issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2337327#comment-9143781) for more details about the above screenshot. And/or have a look at the video about [How to generate crosstab reports with graphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZY5T3kPXZc) (Forena also supports charting of those data, a typical related requirement ...).